# Check the login status and save the login sessions(PHP)

Tags: php, login-script

I am working on a log-in system, Whenever the user tries to access the non-authorized page 
then he should return on the login page to login, how can I perform it

Below is my log-in script

```
<?php

session_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$db_username="root"; // Mysql username 
$db_password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="designshop"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="member"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$db_username", "$db_password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$member_username=$_POST['member_username']; 
$password=$_POST['password']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$member_username = stripslashes($member_username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$member_username = mysql_real_escape_string($member_username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE member_username='$member_username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['member_username']=$_POST['member_username'];
$_SESSION['password']=$_POST['password'];

header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
header("location:try_again.html");
}
?>
```

Comment: you should at least read how to use session ?

Comment: one more thing dont save the password into your session, its a bad practice

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Also Use `mysqli_*`  or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*`

Comment: Instead of rolling your own authentication and ALL the masses of problems that poses for the unwary, why not use one of the many libraries that are available eg OpenID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put this at the top underneath `session_start()`...

```
   if(!empty($_SESSION['member_username'])){header("location: login_success.php");}
```

Like so...

```
session_start();

 if(!empty($_SESSION['member_username'])){
 header("location: login_success.php");}

 $host="localhost"; // Host name 
 $db_username="root"; // Mysql username 
 $db_password=""; // Mysql password 
 //REST OF CODE
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to check for the existence (and non-emptiness) of `$_SESSION['member_username']`. If it is set, that means that your user is logged in, and therefore, there is no need for him to relog.

*Notes:*

- There is no need to store the user's password in session: in fact, its better not to.
- You do your authentication through MySQL, which means that you store the password in cleartext: **this is a bad practice**. It would be better to retrieve both `username` and `password` from the database based only on the `username`, and do the comparaison in your PHP code: this would allow you, for example, to store `sha1`'d password.

Answer (score 0):

start code with `session_start()` and check if the session is set whenever any user trying to access the page, if session is set then redirect to the page otherwise redirect to login page

you can check using isset()

Answer (score 0):

follow this code...

```
 <?php session_start();
    include('conn.php');
    $Name = $_POST['login_id'];
    $Pass = $_POST['password'];
    $select="select * from admin_login where admin_name='$Name' AND admin_pwd='$Pass'";
    $query=mysql_query($select) or die($select);
    $rows=mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $row=mysql_num_rows($query);


    if($row != 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['admin_name']=$rows['admin_name'];
        echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php'</script>";

    }else
    {
        $message = 'Invalid Username Or Password';
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$message.'")</script>'; 
        echo "<script>window.location.href='login.php'</script>";

    }
    ?>
```

put this code to the top of the every page

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["admin_name"])=='') print('<script>window.location.href="login.php"</script>');
```

Comment: Why use php, to echo a <script> that echoes a redirect.  Why not just redirect with header(), straight from php?  Whats the purpose of the javascript?

Comment: i have just given an example.you can use whatever method you like to redirect a page.

Comment: Why on earth would you recommend using a solution that is prone to SQL Injection attacks? And your entire system breaks if javascript is disabled